# How to get the name of the user that created a function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

Is there a direct way to get the owner/creator of a function app under my tenant? I've been trying to find anything inside the resource explorer and so far the only way to know which user deployed this function app is to go to the activity logs.

My objective is get the creators of every function app under my tenant, preferably using ARM Rest API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it through activity logs using portal, powershell, azure cli and REST API. More info in here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit